# Laravel Eloquent mutiple counts with different conditions in one query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have code like below:

```
$sendto_hikkou1 = Guest::where('mypage_id', $mypage)
                ->where('snd_to_hikkou_id', 1)->count();
$sendto_hikkou2 = Guest::where('mypage_id', $mypage)
                ->where('snd_to_hikkou_id', 2)->count();
$sendto_hikkou3 = Guest::where('mypage_id', $mypage)
                ->where('snd_to_hikkou_id', 3)->count();
```

How can I write this in one query?

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupBy` to get all counts in one query, like below

```
$sendto_hikkou = Guest::where('mypage_id', $mypage)
    ->whereIn('snd_to_hikkou_id',[1,2,3])
    ->groupBy('snd_to_hikkou_id')
    ->select('snd_to_hikkou_id',DB::raw("count(*) as hikkou_count"))
    ->get();
```

Comment: Great, i have just found the solution but your code is much better! Tks. But i have another problem, where snd_to_hikkou_id= 1-> have no result so it doesnt return the total =0; I can i fix this?

Comment: Please share what solution you already found, we are here to learn.

Comment: oh sorry, i will share now

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use DB facade instead of the model.
Select the id field then count , group by id then get.
I cant test at this time !

Comment: Thank you, i have just found the solution!
And it uses DB facade ^^

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution i found, but @C2486's answer is much better.

```
        $sendto_hikkou = Guest::where('mypage_id', $mypage)
        ->select(
          \DB::raw('COUNT(IF( snd_to_hikkou_id = 1, snd_to_hikkou_id, NULL)) AS item1'),
          \DB::raw('COUNT(IF( snd_to_hikkou_id = 2, snd_to_hikkou_id, NULL)) AS item2'),
          \DB::raw('COUNT(IF( snd_to_hikkou_id = 3, snd_to_hikkou_id, NULL)) AS item3'),
        )
       ->get();
```